# SQL database restyling

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, database-design

In the latest days I have called to substitute a former dba in my company
Just to summarize, the company is responsible in metereological data storage.
That is, since 1996, lots of variables have been measured and stored in different ways (txt, xls, then access and so on)
During last year, all these data had to be stored in a sql db (sql server 2008 r2) but i found a strange and not straightforward situation
In practice, there are about 30 tables, each with different number of columns.
Every column IS a variable, and in our db more than 300 variables are present
The structure of the tables is similar:
id, siteid, date_of_meas, var1, var2,...,varN (replicated 30 times)

First of all, the variables are not logically grouped (pressure with temperature and so on), but worst to say, everytime a new var is created (depending on practical factors, nothing interesting to discuss here), the former dba acted this way:
1. add a new column to an existing table (...what if a table has already 50 columns...?)
2. write data
As you can figure out, this way it seems to me really crazy

I would re-design from scratch the data structure.
This is the situation: there's a table containing all the existing variables (no problem to add new ones)
I could use the id number of the variables, create new tables (grouping them logically...but there will always be lots of tables) and insert the data with these foreign keys.
Something like the following:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MyMeteo](
[id_meteo] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[varid] [int] NOT NULL,
[siteid] [int] NOT NULL,
[date] [smalldatetime] NOT NULL,
[value] [float] NULL,
```

....

The other problrm is the really huge quantity of data...since data are measured every 30 minutes, in 1 year there are 17520 or 17568 measurements. 
Multiply this for 15 years, 300 variables and 200 sites...I am mondering if a sql db is still the correct choice.
Thanks a lot 
Diego

Comment: Don't worry about the quantity of data. As long as your hardware is up to scratch and you buy the correct edition of SQL server that aspect will be fine.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization

Comment: "not logically grouped (pressure with temperature and so on)" — but then, [`PV = NkT`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ideal_gas_law). To me, it actually seems logical.

Comment: Look into table partitioning for faster query access but the volume of data is nothing SQL Server cannot handle.

Answer (score 5):

> Something like the following:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MyMeteo](
[id_meteo] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[varid] [int] NOT NULL,
[siteid] [int] NOT NULL,
[date] [smalldatetime] NOT NULL,
[value] [float] NULL,
```

… is a slight variation of the [entity-attribute-value](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity-attribute-value_model) pattern. It is an *anti*-pattern.

Your former DBA probably had things right: one row per measurement, with each variable as a column. It matters little if this means 50 or more columns.

Split logical groups in separate tables if you want. Actually, don't: you'll get more complicated query plans and slower queries (sometimes much slower, when ordering by a criteria stored in one table while filtering by a criteria stored in another), i.e. roughly zero benefit for your trouble.

Put simply, what matters for you in the end is how simple it is to mine the data. Splitting your data across tables is going to make this worse. Using a pseudo EAV store like the one you're looking into will make things *much* worse.

Regarding that last point, SQL is the correct choice: 16 billion rows, while impressive, is only notches above small for modern databases.

Answer (score 0):

EAV is an anti-pattern if the data can otherwise be statically relationally mapped.
I am far from sure that is the case here.

We seem to be talking about a variable set of variables: not only are new ones added, but i guess some get out of use over time.

Having hundreds of columns means a seperate static query for every time i want to mine data, whereas in this case EAV gives me the possibilty to very simply gather, say, all measurements of variableX over a given time period, with a very simple reusable query. Indexing on the variable ID might also speed up actions on the database, since a database with 50 columns that are mostly empty will take a lot longer to search (unless you index all 50 columns, even though they are probably 98% of the time empty).

Whether EAV is optimal in this situation is open to debate as I think we have not all the information to decide that, but simply stating that EAV is always an anti-pattern is not construuctive, I think.

Comment: But then, real-life queries seldom are those simple selects of varX, no? :-) In my own software ghetto, they're more like: show a set of variables that fit some criteria on another set, then aggregate the data to compute stats, possibly by grouping on yet another set, filter the mess, and order by a few more bits and pieces. With OP's EAV idea, it's a frankenstein mess of joins that is just about impossible to plan (let alone execute) efficiently. Without, it's a straightforward select/aggregate plan; a few strategically placed indexes here and there, and the result will pop up in no time.

Comment: Sure, but real life is also seldomly black or white when it comes to the best approach. Still in your more complicated queries, i would rather not have to deal with columnames like var123 and var543 in every select or join. EAV is really bad in a lot of cases, i fully agree, but that doesn;t mean it does not have its applications. And i have the feeling that this might not be such a bad candidate :)

Comment: I respectfully disagree. The only place I've ever seen EAVs be useful is to store meta data. The operating word here is "meta": fields that you'd seldom if ever find in any place within a query across an application's lifetime. Anything short of that deserves a (properly typed) column in my own experience. Good EAV candidates include: display_name_pref for a user, template_name for a web page, i.e. stuff that is only of interest in app-land. If it can go in a JSON blob, it can go in an EAV store… Bad ones include anything that might show up in an aggregate function or in a where clause.